# Changing a folder name in a Windows 10 profile, but access it using the old name

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, rename, search-folder

I have the following folders in "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/" : Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 and so on. I want the user to be able to **change** its **name**, but still being able to **access** it using "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/**Folder#**/" (# = number from 1-9).

*For example if the user changes folder1's name to "HomeWork" I want to access it with "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/Folder1"*

Comment: [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: I've looked some of these up, but don't fully understand the differences yet. Just to clarify I prefer not to have to recreate that symbolic/hard link everytime the user changes the folder name. Is that possible with these methods? So I want to be able to acces the folder with ../documents/folder1. And then let the user change its name as many times as he wants using the right click -> change name function. So the user doesn't have to use a different gui or so.